# Generation of simulated data

Tags: regression, robust

I want to generate some data . For example I would generate three variables.2 Independent,1 dependent.

Comment: Welcome to the web-site! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Answer is encyclopedic in length. Start by reading this http://hedibert.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/1949MetropolisUlam.pdf

Comment: Do you have any preferred programming language or software package that you would like to use?

Answer (score 2):

Generating data needs software to do. R is a free software tool that is frequently used for such purposes. It offers a number of functions for random numbers from different distributions

`runif` for random numbers from uniform distributions

`rnorm` for random numbers from normal distribution

The following should fulfill the job in the question:

```
first <- rnorm(100, mean = 100, sd = 10)
second <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 100)
dependent <- 2*first + 3*second + runif(100)
```